# How to detect collision in a toy car

Tags: motor, sensor, dc-motor

I am creating a small car which can change its direction upon collision with a wall or an obstacle. For example, if the car is going north, upon collision it will start going south. I have no idea how to detect the collision.

Comment: Please *edit your question for clarity*.  You are asking two different questions -- do you want to know how to detect a collision in a toy car, or do you want to know how change the direction of the motor's spin if it is stopped (which is hard, because if the motor is stopped it's not spinning).

Comment: There were toys for a long while doing this in a totally mechanical way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Bumpers connected to switches, if I remember correctly -- if the rear bumper is pushed in it goes forward, if the front bumper is pushed in it goes backward, and the bumpers are connected with a bar so they move together.

Comment: @TimWescott No, there is some mechanism with geared wheels that was somehow turning around once it "felt" the wheel is not propelling the platform. Can't find it unfortunately

Comment: @Eugene Sh the really cheap ones had a castor wheel sort of thing in the front (the outer visible front wheels don't actually touch the ground well; these inner castor wheels do). The castor wheels continuously rotate about the vertical axis. When hitting an obstacle, given sufficient time, the castor wheel would rotate completely left or right and then the car would steer that way and move away from the wall. The down side is that, in the absence of obstacles, the car continuously turns slightly left or right amd wouldn't travel perfectly straight. I didn't explain it well :(

Comment: To detect collision, IR LED and IR sensor. If any obstacle is close by, the LED light will reflect back onto the sensor. If sufficiently close, even black objects will reflect enough light. This way, you can avoid collision just before it happens.

Comment: Measuring current for motor. Then car stops at some obstacle, current is going up. Another way to use accelerometer.

Comment: Typical hobbysts use ultrasonic sensors.

Answer (score 1):

conceptual dwg.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1bC1A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The mic will create some pulse with some polarity. This will be strong enough to compare and take evasive action.  You could also clap your hands to do the same task.